# Very large array in initializer list

Tags: c++, list-initialization

I need to initialize large conversion table as data member in my class:

```
CFoo::CFoo() :
    member_one(123),
    member_two(456),
    member_large_table({
       {"huge", "2D"},
       {"array", "of"},
       {"data", "..."},
       .....
```

What is good practice to do this? Placing it in initialization array adds compilation-time error check, but bloat up code of constructor. How to separate this code?

Comment: What is your compilation error? Is it something about .cpp file being to large? I think C++ compilers have very large limit for cpp file size.

Comment: What type has `member_large_table`? You could think about adding a factory function and call that in the initlalizer list.

Comment: Well, the initialisation has to be somewhere. What code would you prefer to be bloated instead of the constructor? Why would it be better to bloat that instead?

Comment: @n314159 `member_large_table` is class, which takes array in constructor. Maybe better to call it like "CSomeConverter"

Comment: Create `make_large_table` function? so you move that code elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `table_t` be the type of `member_large_table`. Then you can do the following:

```
class CFoo {
    static auto make_member_large_table() -> table_t {
        return table_t{{"huge", "2D"},{"array", "of"},{"data", "..."},...};
    }
public: 
    CFoo::CFoo() :
        member_one(123),
        member_two(456),
        member_large_table(make_member_large_table())
    {}
};
```

Due to return value optimization, this will create the table directly in the member variable and no copies or moves will occur.